# How to get the environment variable name in nginx config

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have nginx server up running as docker with base image openresty/openresty:1.15.8.3-buster.

In the docker file I have an environment variable that I am passing as below
ENV UPLOAD_FOLDER /sharedvolume
How do I access this variable with in nginx.config?

I tried using set_by_lua as below
set_by_lua $store_path 'return os.getenv("UPLOAD_FOLDER")';
But the store_path value was giving nil

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/8c9968bd471829c94a5a1856d1cf2dc175044181/README.markdown#system-environment-variable-support):

> ## System Environment Variable Support
>
> If you want to access the system environment variable, say, `foo`, in Lua via the standard Lua API [os.getenv](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv), then you should also list this environment variable name in your `nginx.conf` file via the [env directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env). For example,
>
> ```
>  env foo;
> ```

So add `env UPLOAD_FOLDER;` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the input. I tired this but it didnt work . still in my lua script i get it as nil. I have an http directive which includes one server directive. First i tried to include env UPLOAD_FOLDER; in server directive block but it gave me error saying its not allowed there so gave it in http and in lua i tried calling it as os.getenv(UPLOAD_FOLDER)|os.getenv("UPLOAD_FOLDER") but didnt work

Comment: "in server directive block" There's your problem. The documentation says "Context: `main`".

Comment: My config is like http is the main directive that has one server and multiple location http{server{ location1 location2 ...}} . I have added env UPLOAD_FOLDER; to http the second time and it didnt complaint but when i run the server it give me nil value for this environment value